# Связать две таблицы в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

есть два класса, описывающие две таблицы соответственно:

Класс Service

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String srvcode;
    @Column
    private String srvname;
    
    public Service() {
        
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSrvcode() {
        return srvcode;
    }

    public void setSrvcode(String srvcode) {
        this.srvcode = srvcode;
    }

    public String getSrvname() {
        return srvname;
    }

    public void setSrvname(String srvname) {
        this.srvname = srvname;
    }
}
```

Класс OtherService

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "other_service")
public class OtherService {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String srvcode;
    @Column
    private String srvname;
    @Column
    private int type;


    public OtherService() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSrvcode() {
        return srvcode;
    }

    public void setSrvcode(String srvcode) {
        this.srvcode = srvcode;
    }

    public String getSrvname() {
        return srvname;
    }

    public void setSrvname(String srvname) {
        this.srvname = srvname;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как связать эти классы (таблицы) по полям Service.srvcode = OtherService.srvcode, чтобы в итоге получить все поля из Service и поле OtherService.type?

**UPDATE**

Попробовала реализовать так:

Создала новый класс, который содержит поля из Service и OtherService

ServiceNew

```
public class ServiceNew {
    private int id;
    private String srvcode;
    private String srvname;
    private int type;
    
    public ServiceNew() {
        
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSrvcode() {
        return srvcode;
    }

    public void setSrvcode(String srvcode) {
        this.srvcode = srvcode;
    }

    public String getSrvname() {
        return srvname;
    }

    public void setSrvname(String srvname) {
        this.srvname = srvname;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Запрос:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.
        createQuery("select srv.id, srv.srvname, srv.srvcode, osrv.type from Service srv join OtherService osrv on srv.srvcode = osrv.srvcode", Object[].class);

List<ServiceNew> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (Object[] results : query.getResultList()) {
    ServiceNew sNew = new ServiceNew();
    sNew.setId((int) results[0]);
    sNew.setSrvname((String) results[1]);
    sNew.setSrvcode((String) results[2]);
    sNew.setType((int) results[3]);

    list.add(sNew);
}

System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Для начала опишите чем сервис отличается от другого сервиса и зачем их разделять на две таблицы.

Comment: Не знаю, так было реализовано и менять что-то не могу, нужно просто их связать по полю srvcode.

Comment: Во втором сервисе одно поле забыла, обновила вопрос, добавив еще одно поле

Comment: Попробуйте начать свое путешествие тут https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one

Comment: Я так пробовала, в первый сервис добавляла следующее @OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "srvcode")
private OtherService otherService; ошибку выдает что названия "srvcode" полей дублируются

Comment: Пропали что-то.

Comment: Что значит связать?

Comment: Есть две таблицы Service.srvcode OtherService.srvcode сделать join по полю srvcode. Если бы таблица Service содержала ссылку на id OtherService или наоборот проблем бы не было, а тут в этом случае не могу понять как реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить двумя способами.

### Использование таблицы связей

Создайте сущность `SrvCode`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "srv_code")
public class SrvCode {

    @Id
    @Column("code")
    public String code;
}
```

И привяжите сущность `Service` к только что созданной сущности при помощи `@JoinColumn`. Для того, чтобы нельзя было создать две сущности `Service`, которые относятся к одному и тому же `SrvCode`, используйте стратегию **One to One**. Поставьте ограничение уникальности на колонку `srvCode` в таблице `services`.

Ваша сущность `Service` в итоге должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class Service {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "srv_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
    public SrvCode srvCode;
}
```

Всё то же самое выполняем для сущности `OtherService`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "other_services")
public class OtherService {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "srv_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
    public SrvCode srvCode;
}
```

Сущность `SrvCode`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "srv_code")
public class SrvCode {

    @Id
    @Column("code")
    public String code;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "srvCode")
    public Service service;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "srvCode")
    public OtherService otherService;
}
```

### Использование особенностей JPQL

В `Spring` есть возможность формировать DTO прямо в запросе. То есть вы могли бы сделать как-то вот так:

```sql
SELECT new com.example.app.dto.MyDto(s.id, os.id) 
FROM Service s
JOIN OtherService os ON os.srvCode = s.srvCode
```

Comment: Нет, не может, одной записи в Service относится одна запись в OtherService. А можете в ваш ответ добавить пример связки с помощью JoinColumn?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна хорошо, сейчас допишу

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна обновлённый ответ решает вашу проблему?

Comment: Сейчас попробую переделать код и посмотрю

Comment: Вопрос возник, запустил ваш код, но таблица srv_code пустая почему-то. И когда пытаюсь из Service получить данные из OtherService так service.getSrvCode().getOtherService().getType() выдает ошибку. Таблицы создаются и заполняются при запуске приложения, может ли поэтому новая таблица srv_code пустой оуказаться?

Comment: Если они заполняются при старте приложения, то вам надо и в таблицу srv_code также данные вручную вставить. Вы, я полагаю, используете скрипт data.sql? Добавьте в него данные

Comment: Нет, заполняются они из XML. Т.е. читаю XML-ки в коллекции и методом saveAll() из JpaRepository сохраняю данные. А есть способ без использования промежуточной таблицы srv_code?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна ну это не совсем нормально будет. Потому что у вас одна сущность должна будет ссылаться на другую. а вы, я так понимаю, хотите, чтобы сущности друг на друга ссылались. Так не получится.

Comment: Вообще задача у меня следующая. Есть таблицы Service и OtherService таблица OtherService содержит поле type, которая нужна в программе дальше. Хочу объединить эти две таблицы или каким-то образом получить сводную, где все поля из Service и поле type из OtherService. Смотрю примеры как это реализовано, везде чтобы на HQL такое объединение сделать обязательно в классе нужно была связка OneToOne или OneToMany.  Уже думаю может по старинке с помощью jdbc обычный join запрос что ли написать. Если других вариантов нет

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна вы можете сделать это при помощи JPQL, создавая DTO прямо в запросе. Отредактируйте свой вопрос, я поправлю ответ

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна да и не обязательно там связка нужна. Ничто не мешает вам сделать JOIN по условию

Comment: Изменила вопрос.

Comment: Такой вариант тоже пробовала TypedQuery<Service> query = entityManager.createQuery("select Service.srvcode, Service.srvname, Otherservice.type from Service join Otherservice on Service.srvcode = Otherservice.srvcode", Service.class);
System.out.println(query.getResultList());  но получала ошибку Could not interpret path expression 'Service.srvcode'

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста конец моего вопроса. Я создала новый класс, содержащий нужные поля из двух таблиц и написала запрос. Вроде получилось.. Такой способ приемлем или есть лучшее решение?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна да, это абсолютно нормальный вариант. Я сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна проверьте, подходит ли вам мой ответ. И переработайте вопрос, чтобы он был понятен - сейчас у вас каша в вопросе, не понятно, что вы конкретно пытаетесь решить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне нужно было из двух таблиц Service и OtherService получить сводную, содержащую несколько полей из Service и одно поле из OtherService. Сделала как выше в своем вопросе описала. Меня смущало только то что TypedQuery<Object[]> параметризован массивом объектов. Я думала можно попроще как-то сделать.

Comment: Могли бы дать ссылку на статью с примерами про JPOL?

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна конкретную не найду, попробуйте посмотреть на baeldung.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое.